# TypeError: string indices must be integers while parsing JSON, Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse JSON, below is my code.

```
import requests
import json
yatoken = '123123sdfsdf'
listOfId = ['11111111111', '2222222222', '33333333333']
for site in listOfId:
   r = requests.get('http://api.ya-bot.net/projects/' + site  + '?token=' + yatoken)
parsed = json.loads(r.text)

for url in parsed['project']:
   #print url
   print str(url['name'])
```

And JSON:

```
{
"project":{
"id":"123123sdfsdfs",
"urls":[],
"name":"Имя",
"group":"Группа",
"comments":"",
"sengines":[],
"wordstat_template":1,
"wordstat_regions":[]
}
}
```

It gives this error

```
    print str(url['name'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How I can fix this problem?
Thx.

Comment: Just so you know, you can replace `parsed = json.loads(r.text)` with `parsed = r.json()`, requests has that built in.

Answer (score 2):

The `'project'` key refers to a dictionary. Looping over that dictionary gives you *keys*, each a string. You are not looping over the list of URLs. One of those keys will be `'name'`

Your code is confusing otherwise. You appear to want to get each URL. To do that, you'd have to loop over the `'urls'` key in that nested dictionary:

```
for url in parsed['project']['urls']:
    # each url value
```

In your sample response that list is *empty* however.

If you wanted to get the `'name'` key from the nested dictionary, just print it without looping:

```
print parsed['project']['name']
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> parsed = json.loads('''\
... {
... "project":{
... "id":"123123sdfsdfs",
... "urls":[],
... "name":"Имя",
... "group":"Группа",
... "comments":"",
... "sengines":[],
... "wordstat_template":1,
... "wordstat_regions":[]
... }
... } 
... ''')
>>> parsed['project']
{u'group': u'\u0413\u0440\u0443\u043f\u043f\u0430', u'name': u'\u0418\u043c\u044f', u'wordstat_regions': [], u'comments': u'', u'urls': [], u'sengines': [], u'id': u'123123sdfsdfs', u'wordstat_template': 1}
>>> parsed['project']['name']
u'\u0418\u043c\u044f'
>>> print parsed['project']['name']
Имя
>>> print parsed['project']['urls']
[]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: How can i get 'name' of this listOfId = ['11111111111', '2222222222', '33333333333'] ? Without loop?

Comment: I have *no idea* what you are asking there.

Comment: sorry. we have 3 'id': '11111111111', '2222222222', '33333333333'. I want to get 3 'names' and use this: for site in listOfId. But I receive 1 result

Comment: But there is no list of names. What did you want to match this agains, your sample response is just *one* `project` object. Again, you are not being clear as to how the values in `listOfId` should map to the data returned from the API.

Comment: 1. i do request: http://api.ya-bot.net/projects/' + site  + '?token=' + yatoken, where **site** is one of **listOfId**.

Comment: If the API only lets you put in one ID at a time, you have no choice but to use a loop. Look at the API documentation.

Comment: "you have no choice but to use a loop": can you give me example?

Answer (score 1):

`for url in parsed['project']` returns a dict so you are actually iterating over the `keys` of the dict so `"id"["name"]` etc.. is going to error, you can use `d = parsed['project']` to get the dict then access the dict by key to get whatever value you want.

```
d = parsed['project']
print(d["name"])
print(d["urls"])
...
```

Or iterate over the items to get key and value:

```
 for k, v in parsed['project'].items():
     print(k,v)
```

If you print what is returned you can see exactly what is happening:

```
In [17]: js = {
"project":{
"id":"123123sdfsdfs",
"urls":[],
"name":"Имя",
"group":"Группа",
"comments":"",
"sengines":[],
"wordstat_template":1,
"wordstat_regions":[]
}
}

In [18]: js["project"] # dict
Out[18]: 
{'comments': '',
 'group': 'Группа',
 'id': '123123sdfsdfs',
 'name': 'Имя',
 'sengines': [],
 'urls': [],
 'wordstat_regions': [],
 'wordstat_template': 1}

In [19]: for k in js["project"]: # iterating over the keys of the dict
   ....:     print(k)
   ....:     
sengines # k["name"] == error
id
urls
comments
name
wordstat_regions
wordstat_template
group
```