# python json TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I am writing a script for my weather app. I have following json stored in file:

```
"{\"coord\":{\"lon\":21.01,\"lat\":52.23},\"weather\":[{\"id\":801,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"few clouds\",\"icon\":\"02d\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":21,\"pressure\":1023,\"humidity\":43,\"temp_min\":21,\"temp_max\":21},\"visibility\":10000,\"wind\":{\"speed\":2.6,\"deg\":20},\"clouds\":{\"all\":20},\"dt\":1502098200,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":5374,\"message\":0.002,\"country\":\"PL\",\"sunrise\":1502075224,\"sunset\":1502129710},\"id\":756135,\"name\":\"Warsaw\",\"cod\":200}"
```

My code:

```
def get_image(json_file):

    json_file = "{}/{}".format(jsons_save_path, json_file)

    f = open(json_file, 'r')
    echo2 = f.read()
    data1 = json.loads(echo2)
    f.close()

    print(data1)
    print(type(data1))

    image_id = data1['weather'][0]['icon']
    print(image_id)

    return
```

I get following error when I run the function:

```
  File "./get_weather.py", line 79, in get_image
image_id = data1['weather'][0]['icon']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any help would be appreciated.

As is was asked in comments, here is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import http.client
import os
from shutil import copyfile


key = '...'
city_id = '756135'

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('api.openweathermap.org')
payload = "{}"

jsons_save_path = '/shares/scripts/weather/jsons'

def get_current_weather():

conn.request("GET", "/data/2.5/weather?id=%s&units=metric&APPID=%s" % (city_id, key), payload)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

data = data.decode("utf-8")

# print(json.loads(data))
save_to_file(data, 'current.json')
get_image('current.json')

return

def get_5_days():

conn.request("GET", "/data/2.5/forecast?id=%s&units=metric&APPID=%s" % (city_id, key), payload)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

data = data.decode("utf-8")

# print(json.loads(data)) 
save_to_file(data, 'forecast.json')

return

def save_to_file(data, file_name):

tmp_file_name = "{}/{}.tmp".format(jsons_save_path, file_name)
final_file = "{}/{}".format(jsons_save_path, file_name)

with open(tmp_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ':'))
    print("json files saved to tmp")

g = open(tmp_file_name, 'r')
echo = g.read()
g.close()

try:
    test_json = json.loads(echo)
    print('json is fine')
    copyfile(tmp_file_name, final_file)
except ValueError as e:
    print('invalid json with error: %' % e)
    return None

return

def get_image(json_file):

json_file = "{}/{}".format(jsons_save_path, json_file)

f = open(json_file, 'r')
echo2 = f.read()
data1 = json.loads(echo2)
f.close()

print(data1)
print(type(data1))

image_id = data1['weather'][0]['icon']
print(image_id)

return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_current_weather()
    get_5_days()
```

Error that I am getting:

```
./get_weather.py 
json files saved to tmp
json is fine
{"coord":{"lon":21.01,"lat":52.23},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":21,"pressure":1023,"humidity":43,"temp_min":21,"temp_max":21},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.6},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1502100000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5374,"message":0.0081,"country":"PL","sunrise":1502075226,"sunset":1502129707},"id":756135,"name":"Warsaw","cod":200}
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "./get_weather.py", line 85, in <module>
> get_current_weather()
> File "./get_weather.py", line 27, in get_current_weather
> get_image('current.json')
> File "./get_weather.py", line 79, in get_image
> image_id = data1['weather'][0]['icon']
> TypeError: string indices must be integers
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: string indices must be integers while parsing JSON, Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229546/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-while-parsing-json-python)

Comment: That code would not give an that error; as posted, it works just fine. Please show your actual code and the full output (including the prints).

Comment: Could you print image_id with  image_id = data1['weather']? What is the output?

Comment: when doing  image_id = data1['weather'] I get the same result

Comment: And what is the output if you print data1?

Comment: print(data1) show - {"coord":{"lon":21.01,"lat":52.23},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":21,"pressure":1023,"humidity":43,"temp_min":21,"temp_max":21},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.6},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1502100000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5374,"message":0.0081,"country":"PL","sunrise":1502075226,"sunset":1502129707},"id":756135,"name":"Warsaw","cod":200}

Comment: print(type(data1)) is <class 'str'>

Comment: well, if `data1` is a string, then of course you can't index into it with a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your 'json' file.
What you actually have stored there is a string, *not* a load of json data.

It does validate as valid json however, as a string on its own *is* valid json, therefore the json parser does not throw an error.

So what you are doing is loading the contents of your file and parsing it as json.  This provides one string as the data, and this cannot be indexed by string, as you are trying to do (as it isn't a dict).

Your file should look like:

```
{"coord":{"lon":21.01,"lat":52.23},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":21,"pressure":1023,"humidity":43,"temp_min":21,"temp_max":21},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":20},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1502098200,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5374,"message":0.002,"country":"PL","sunrise":1502075224,"sunset":1502129710},"id":756135,"name":"Warsaw","cod":200}
```

(on one line)
or:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 21.01,
        "lat": 52.23
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 801,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "few clouds",
        "icon": "02d"
    }],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 21,
        "pressure": 1023,
        "humidity": 43,
        "temp_min": 21,
        "temp_max": 21
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.6,
        "deg": 20
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 20
    },
    "dt": 1502098200,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 5374,
        "message": 0.002,
        "country": "PL",
        "sunrise": 1502075224,
        "sunset": 1502129710
    },
    "id": 756135,
    "name": "Warsaw",
    "cod": 200
}
```

(this is pretty-printed, the newlines / tabulation are not needed)

Why is your file incorrect?

What you are doing is obtaining the json data *as a string* from the api.  At this point, so save it to file, it just needs to be written.

Instead, you use `json.dump()` which is intended to output data as a json file.
And it does just that.  It creates a json file consisting of just the one string that you give it.

Just replace your

```
json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ':'))
```

line with

```
outfile.write(data)
```

and it should work.

Comment: I get my json from 'api.openweathermap.org'. I get it with my get_current_weather() function and store it to file save_to_file(data, file_name) function.